# How do I define a recurring IP range for AWS security groups?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

We are running an environment on AWS that is becoming more complex day in and day out. I'd like to have some ability to define IP source ranges that I will use again and again though with changing ports and protocols.

A simple example is allowing HTTP, HTTPS, SSH and MySQL access from our office network to different servers. Sometimes within the environment itself this is possible by defining a "mute" security group that I can then reference as the range. Is this possible for IP ranges outside of AWS?

Answer (score 2):

We ended up writing a script that makes use of the [AWS CLI tools](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to generate our security groups. In a nutshell it calls [ec2-describe-group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeSecurityGroups.html) to get the current state of the security groups then loops through services & IP address ranges to call [ec2-authorize](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress.html) to add new rules to the security groups.

Scripting this was the best way we could find to manage a fairly complex set of interdependent security groups not only within multiple AWS regions but across multiple office sites as well.  It's worked rather well for a couple years now.  About the only thing I might do differently if I had to redo it all would be to rewrite these scripts in Python using [boto](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), but that's mostly just a personal preference.

Edit: Here's a snippet of the important parts of one of our bash scripts that we use:

```
CORPORATE_NETBLOCKS="1.2.3.4/24 4.3.2.1/27"
REMOTE_OFFICE="5.6.7.8/32"
...
ec2-describe-group --show-empty-fields > $TMPGRPFILE
...
echo "Allow access to the utility server"
grp=${myregion}-util
for cidr in $CORPORATE_NETBLOCKS $REMOTE_OFFICE; do
  for p in 22 80 443 8000-8080; do
    ptest=$(echo $p | sed -e 's/-/[[:space:]]+/')
    egrep "PERMISSION.*${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.*${grp}[[:space:]].*ALLOWS.*tcp.*${ptest}.*CIDR.*${cidr}.*ingress" $TMPGRPFILE > /dev/null
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
      echo "$cidr -> $grp:${p} already in place"
      continue
    fi
    CMD="ec2-authorize -P tcp -p ${p} -s $cidr $grp"
    # echo $CMD
    $CMD
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "Failed to create permission. Line $LINENO"
      exit 2
    fi
  done
done
```

The script has a dozen or so loops similar to this one that grep for various ports/cidrs in the output from ec2-describe-group and call ec2-authorize to add any rules that aren't already in place.

Comment: Could you include some code?  This is all very vague.

Comment: It seems surprising to me that there is no built-in feature for this. Seems like a pretty standard thing to do. Just recently moved over the AWS.